# How can i pass parameter in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, frontend

How can i pass `this.state.posts.length` to items in React.js so i can get a dynamic number instead of `1`, find below my variables.

```
const notEnough = {
  Larga: {
    breakpoint: { max: 4000, min: 0 },
    items: 1
  }
};
```

I have a condition in responsive props, if the lenght of posts is < 5, i need to pass the `this.state.posts.length` value to items.

```
responsive={this.state.posts.length < 5 ? notEnough : responsive}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now `notEnough` is an `object`, you can turn it into a `function` which takes some `parameters` (`posts.length`) and returns an `object`.

```
const notEnough = items =>({
  Larga: {
    breakpoint: { max: 4000, min: 0 },
    items
  })
};

responsive={this.state.posts.length < 5 ? notEnough(this.state.posts.length) : responsive}
```

If `notEnought` is declared inside your component you don't really need to do that

```
const notEnough = {
  Larga: {
    breakpoint: { max: 4000, min: 0 },
    items: this.state.posts.length
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you're adding an unnecessary intermediary step.  If you want 2 different variables to depend on the same condition, you can just insert the same condition in both places, assuming you're declaring this const somewhere it will respond to state changes:

```
const notEnough = {
  Larga: {
    breakpoint: { max: 4000, min: 0 },
    items: this.state.posts.length < 5 ? this.state.posts.length : 1;
  }
};
```